# How to set a timeout for a gearman job

Tags: php, gearman

I want to set a timeout duration for Gearman jobs. For instance, I don't want a gearman job to run for more than 30 seconds, and if the job is running for more than 30 seconds it should be stopped and the next job is started.

Is this possible with Gearman? (I'm using the Gearman PHP API on Centos 6.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [GearmanWorker::timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.timeout.php) here is a [Good Example](http://www.php.net/gearmanworker.settimeout#refsect1-gearmanworker.settimeout-examples)

```
//Set Timeout
$gmworker->setTimeout(5000);

echo "Waiting for job...\n";

// Start working 
while ( @$gmworker->work() || $gmworker->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT ) {
    if ($gmworker->returnCode() == GEARMAN_TIMEOUT) {
        // Normally one would want to do something useful here ...
        continue;
    }

    if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
        // Somthign failed
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong - setTimeout only works on no socket io, worker can run for whatever time it wants. I've just tried adding `sleep(3)` after `setTimeout(1000)`, and it does *not* end up in `GEARMAN_TIMEOUT`. Please provide a test case to prove me wrong

Comment: @Fluffy The worker timeout start working when you call `work()`, a sleep before doesn't do anything.